# Plotting variable parameters in a single graph in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

am a beginner in R having undergone a few basic online courses and web material to develop basic understanding. Sadly the question that follows is is a very basic one and on one of the most powerful capabilities of R for which I could not find answers.

**Problem Statement:-** I have a csv file which looks like this

```
         day1   day2   day3   day4    day5   day6 ........ day'n'
Param1    9      8      5       0       0      0             4
Param2    1      3      4       9       1      0             3
Param3    0      0      0       1       2      3             9
Param4
.
.
Param'm'  6      4      0       1       8      3             1
```

I would like to plot the values of these all parameters across 'n' days in a single graph.

That is to say.
 X axis of graph= Range for value of parameters (shown in cell of example above with max value as 10)
 Y axis of graph= days 1 through 'n'.
The plot of every unique parameter can be differentiated by a colour.

What is have tried is this

```
    a <- read.csv("~sults/200000555087.csv_result.csv")
    p<-qplot(data=a,x=names(a[,1:m)),y=c(1:n))
```

which I clearly know is not supposed to work, but was the best I could come up with

There isin't a valid tag for qplot hence tagging GGPLOT2.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to “melt” your plot and colour the groups differently.

You can use the `gather` function from the tidyr package for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

remodeled_data = a %>%
    add_rownames('Param') %>%
    gather(Day, Value, -Param) %>%
    mutate(Day = as.integer(sub('^day', '', Day)))

ggplot(remodeled_data) +
    aes(x = Value, y = Day, color = Param) +
    geom_line()
```

The remodelling expression is read like this:

- First, add an additional column for the rownames, calling it 'Param'.
- Then gather all the columns (except `Param`) into *one* column called `Value`, and put the corresponding column names into a separate column called `Day`.
- Finally, parse out the day number from the `Day` column.

The data then looks as follows:

```
    Param   Day Value
    (chr) (int) (dbl)
1  Param1     1     9
2  Param2     1     1
3  Param3     1     0
4  Param4     1     6
5  Param1     2     8
6  Param2     2     3
…
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, a little web lookup based on your direction suited my need perfectly.